# PHPUnit: How to test a self return method (returns $this)

Tags: php, phpunit

I have the following method that returns itself to allow methods chaining.

```
class MyClass
{
    public function myMethod()
    {
        // Do something

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Now, when i test this method it's all ok. But PHPUnit code coverage tells me that the last line, the return, isn't tested: the line of "return $this", infact, is marked in red and the .

In my test i have used this to test that the method returns itself:

```
public function testMyMethod()
{
    $myClass = new MyClass;

    // Test that returns true if properly set
    $result = $myClass->myMethod();

    $this->assertInstanceOf('MyClass', $result);
}
```

The test obviously passed, but the return line is ever marked in red and the coverage report tells that the method is not fully tested.

How can i reach the "All Green" bar?

Comment: If your objective in testing is simply to get the "all green" bar, then you're not testing for the right reasons

Comment: As long as you know that you have tested it properly then that is fine. The fact that the software does not recognize that you have tested it all is 'not your problem'. 100 percent code coverage does not mean that the code is correct. I like unit tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mark Baker and @Ryan Vincent, as both you pointed out, it isn't a good habit to test only to reach the "green bar": i know.

Anyway the reports hlep to better understand the "health" of a class.

I'm not so navigated in unit testing (this is my first real attempt to use it on a real project), but i've read a lot about it and found this same idea: test for testing is not a good thing. Ok, we all agree on this.

But my question comes from another consideration: if unit testing is useful to have a "health" code base, i think that is also useful when this code is shared (or when i will refact it after a lot of time: i use a lot of comments!): another dev can see what i've done, which tests i've wrote, and decide to test more by himself.

So, seeing a "not green bar", cause the new developer to check the code to see if he can improve the tests only to find that it is yet tested and that the "uncomplete bar" is generated simply by a "problem" (generally speaking) that is trivial in reality.

This is a waste of time in my opinion: this is the reason that keeps me to reach the "green bar".

**Anyway, coming back to the question, i think i've found the cause of the problem.
The returning of $this is useful to able the methods to be chained between each other.
So, i didn't reach the green bar because my tests didn't chained those methods, so the "return $this" where never tested.**

When i tested some other methods that used the chaining of those "not-completely-tested" methods, then also the "return $this" line resulted as tested.

This led me to reach the green bar! Now i've got it and i'm also sure that the test tests also for the chaining work well (that is a good thing).

Comment: Thanks for your answer - it will help us. - **merry new year** :-)